# Email Sending with AWS SES service in Codeigniter Version 2.26

Tags: codeigniter-2, amazon-ses

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbeCD.png 
I used AWS SES email service in codeigniter and got issue. i also installed aws sdk via composer. I attached my error as a screenshoot and describe some source code. Anyone can help me to solve this issue. Thank you so much for help.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$mailConfig['mailpath'] = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";
$mailConfig['protocol'] = "smtp";
$mailConfig['smtp_host'] = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
$mailConfig['smtp_user'] = "ses user name";
$mailConfig['smtp_pass'] = 'ses password';
$mailConfig['key'] = "ses-key";
$mailConfig['secret'] = "ses-secret";
$mailConfig['region'] = "us-east-1";
$mailConfig['smtp_port'] = "587";
$mailConfig['mailtype'] = "html";
$mailConfig['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$mailConfig['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
$mailConfig['email_newline'] = "\r\n";
$mailConfig['newline'] = "\r\n";
[enter image description here][1]$mailConfig['validate'] = "TRUE";
```

Comment: whats the error you get. I cant see the screenshot

Comment: Oh sorry i edited the post and attach image again.

Comment: I think your SES credentials are wrong. did you test the credentials

Comment: Yes credentials are correct and it works in laravel project. I think in codeigniter configuration is wrong and need to add something. But i cannot find the solution.

Comment: i think its the sendmail not installed properly

Comment: I just created new gmail account and tested with smtp_host as smtp.gmail.com. And it works. I think this setting and SES config is not match.